# Как добавить в запрос добавление своего параметра?

Tags: sql

Хочу сделать перенос данных из одной таблицы в другую, но мне нужно чтобы при переносе ещё я подставлял своё значение, не подскажите как это можно сделать

Вот сам запрос:

```
INSERT INTO basket_goods (id_product, box, gram) 
SELECT id_product, box, gram 
FROM order_goods
```

Comment: А куда вставлять значение?

Comment: `... select 1 as myCustomValue, id_product, box, gram...`

Comment: Вставить в новую таблицу

Answer (score 1):

Просто возьмите и подставьте:

```sql
INSERT INTO basket_goods (
  id_product
, box
, gram
-- Новый столбец.
, new_field
)
SELECT id_product
     , box
     , gram
-- NB: Подставлено «1».
     , 1
  FROM order_goods
;
```

Comment: Я видимо не точно объяснил, я хочу перенести все данные + добавить ещё одно данные для другого столбца, то есть я переношу 3 столба с данными, но у меня в таблице новой ещё столбец и туда подставляю значение

Comment: @АлександрКорегин  Принцип не меняется так-то.  См. правку.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE NewTable ...

INSERT INTO NewTable (Column1, Column2, Column3, NewColumn)
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    YourValue --сюда можно вставить ваше значение или сделать вычисляемое поле на основе других колонок
FROM OldTable
```

**NewColumn** - новая колонка, в новой балице, которую вы хотите заполнить вашими значениями.
**YourValue** - ваши значения или вычисляемый столбец на основе других колонок.